# Overflow when using Web Part

Tags: css, cewp

I created a dropdown menu using sharepoint list. The issue I'm having is that the sub menu items are getting cut off. The way I'm showing the menu is through the content editor web part linking to an html page that generates the menu.

I'm trying to find out if it's at all possible for me to display content outside of the content editor web part, the overflow specifically. The other alternative is to set the container div height really high so that any dropdown can be seen but that ruins the page as I can't add other webparts below.

This is it here: https://jsfiddle.net/uoydnc8h/4/

It works fine in the fiddle but if I put it in a web part it cuts off

**SOLVED:** It had nothing to do with the CEWP. The issue was the wiki page height. I fixed the issue by simply putting my cursor below the CEWP and hitting enter a few times :/

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what your Webpart overflow looks like. Also why not adjust the dimensions of your webpart?

Comment: I'm working on IE9 and it breaks imgur so I can't add an image. If you look at the fiddle, when you hover over the top level menu, sub menu opens up below, but it's cut off very early. I can make the div or the web part higher, but if I do that, I can't have anything below the menu. That's not really how it should be.

Comment: Adding space after the web part fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Trying setting the z-index of your dropdowns to a high value. That should allow it to show on top of the web part and the rest of the page.

Comment: Hey Erin, I was able to fix the issue. It had to do with the wiki page heigh (surprisingly). After adding some blank spaces after the web part, the menu displayed perfectly fine.